# lost numpy for Keras in R

Tags: r, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I installed Keras, Tensorflow and reticulate packages in R and when I check the version of Python used it's given 3.6 in the r-reticulate folder (so I cannot use Keras as need 3.7). So I run the following line to change the folder to pick up the latest Python version:

```
use_python("C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/", required = TRUE)
```

Now I lost Numpy. How to change the python version in r-reticulate without losing Numpy ? Or can I specify numpy folder ?

```
> library(reticulate)
> reticulate::py_config()
python:         C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda
version:        3.8.3 (default, May 19 2020, 06:50:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

Comment: Can you install numpy in your Python 3.8 installation? Using the correct `pip` binary (likely one in your r-miniconda directory), the command would be `pip install numpy`, or possibly `conda install numpy` instead. It is dependent on how you created your Python 3.8 installation.

Comment: Numpy is already installed and it is located in the following folder: c:\users\Mezeix\anaconda3\lib\site-packages. If I do not use use_python function, R is able to located Numpy but with the wrong Python version. It is when I change Python folder in R that I lost Numpy

Comment: Your python installations at `C:\Users\Mezeix\anaconda3` and `C:\Users\Mezeix\AppData\Local\r-miniconda` are completely independent of one another. If you'd like to use numpy with the `r-miniconda` python, you must install it in that python installation.

Comment: I installed Reticulate and I got Numpy in C:/Users/Mezeix/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy. It is here but with Python 3.6 in r-reticulate that I cannot use with Keras that's why I change the folder using use_python fucntion. If I change I lost Numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You have two installations of Python on your computer which can be thought of as completely different programs. That "program" supports installing "packages", like numpy and tensorflow. If you install numpy in one of those installations, it doesn't provide it in both of them - you have to also install numpy in the second installation.

Your two installations are at `C:\Users\Mezeix\anaconda3` and `C:\Users\Mezeix\AppData\Local\r-miniconda`. I do not know exactly the details of your second installation, but if it is a miniconda installation, there should be some kind of `conda.exe` or `pip.exe`, or perhaps a GUI tool which you can use to install numpy for that Python installation. You would install it the same way you installed tensorflow on this new installation.

Since you're actually using R, it's likely you can use one of reticulate's tools (I am not an R user myself) to install numpy on this new installation, such as `py_install` or `conda_install` ([docs](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/python_packages.html)). When reticulate discusses "environments", keep in mind these are completely independent of one another, and that packages are not shared between different environments. What it seems you really need to do is create an environment with a new enough Python using reticulate, and install both numpy and tensorflow in that environment.